# Did anybody ever measure the watt use (startup, idle/low/intense use, stalling) of a 18 V power tool?

Tags: power, batteries, tools

I am curious about the actual power in watt a 18 V power tool like an angle grinder or router actually use over time (Makita, DeWalt, Bosch, etc.).

I have seen people running such tools not with a battery but with a benchtop power supply. So in theory they could measure the watt use for startup and during idle-, low- and high-power use and even stalling.

I would love to see such watt profiles (little charts) for a router.

I googled my little heart out to find this kind of data with no success. Does anybody know if/where I could get this data?

Comment: They're just DC motors. Do some research on the DC motor equations and you should be able to get a reasonable idea if you have the voltage, the speed and the DC resistance of the motor. The situation will be more complicated if there is battery protection or any kind of current limiting in the speed controller.

Comment: Unless limited electronically, stall current will damage a motor more quickly than it can easily be determined manually by one person working alone. Initial startup current is the same as stall current, but declines very rapidly as the speed increases. Current is the most useful parameter to measure. Power may be calculated rather than measured in most situations. Manufacturers are most concerned with estimating operating life and determining maximum winding temperature for a "typical" duty cycle. You are unlikely to find more than what is marked on the product, the only useful information.

Comment: I don't want to stall and destroy the motor. Also I don't care if you measure DC motors or tools or current and then calculate Watts. I am just interested in the data and am quite surprised nobody has ever measured it?!

Comment: Determine the armature resistance with an ohmmeter or by applying a low voltage and measuring the current with the shaft prevented from turning.Turn the shaft slowly to find the maximum resistance. The resistance will be lower when two commutator segments are shorted together by the brushes. A no-load test will tell you the no-load losses and the volts per RPM. I believe that will give you all of the information for motor curves. The current marked on the tool probably represents the "normal use" point. Geared tools will have a lot of friction loss, and high-speed tools significant windage.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I don't really have any measuring devices. I was just wondering if any measurements of that kind are out there. I just want to get a feeling what for example the Makita 18V router actually draws for light/normal/heavy use.

Something like this would be enough to measure the actual current: https://www.akkuline.de/mainsconnector-ap-mc-5100-18v-ersetzt-makita-makstar-bl1830-akku-15066